# What is this hover menu on mobile website called? is it custom built or third party tool?

Tags: menu, terminology, mobile-web, hover

[image: Website in.mobile.reuters]

I stumbled upon this great browsing experience on reuters mobile site. It uses hovering menu, when clicked opens up a number of other tools such as search, share, font, etc. I was wondering what it is called or is it built by Reuters for their own website or it is available from a third party.

Comment: Reminds me most of the Windows 8 charm bar, though I know it's not unique. Not sure if "charm bar" is accepted as a universal term though

Comment: If you are looking to implement such a feature, and trying to figure out what to search further on, that would not be something we can generally help you with. If you are wondering from a UX point of view - why does it matter what it is called, as long as it is the right tool for the right job.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey If you want to refer to something, it's significantly easier if there is a commonly used name for it than to have to describe it every time.

Comment: @JohnGB, I'm not going to disagree with it being nice to know the name. It isn't a UX issue though.

Comment: I actually have never seen something like this for mobile website so was wondering if I missed out on something. Also, having a commonly known term for such type of tool would be beneficial for having dialogues. As slaterjohn pointed out an example called flyout menu, I think we use that

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey A huge part of UX is communication.  If you are able to design something well, but can't communicate what you've done, you'll have a hard time making a success of most projects. So for me at least, anything to do with communicating UX is part of UX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd imagine their solution is a custom built solution but it doesn't look dissimilar to Path's **Flyout** menu.

A good Javascript example for this can be found on [Codepen here](http://codepen.io/sparanoid/pen/nHAmi).

Path call it a Flyout menu and they were the first people i saw using this on their iOS app so if it's not the official name it should be.